# how to multiply a value inside the column in sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm using vb.net and sql. Below is the example on how my data in my db look like.
I want to multiply the value inside the column UPH with 24 and insert into a new column which is UPD.

[image]

Comment: do you need to do this into your database or into a DataTable in vb.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE yourtable SET UPD = UPH*24;
```

You could also create an insert trigger on the database

```
CREATE TRIGGER times24 BEFORE INSERT ON yourtable FOR EACH ROW SET @UPD = @UPH * 24;
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html for more on that.

Answer (score 1):

Issue an `update` statement like this:

```
UPDATE TableName SET UPD = UPH * 24
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS :

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET UPD = 24*(UPH) WHERE DEVICE ='A'
```